# Creating a list with a nullable generic parameter

Tags: c#, nullable

I want to have a generic class (in type T) that holds a list of nullable Ts.

```
class MyClass<T>
{
     List<T?> myNullableList; 
}
```

This fails to compile with the following error.

> Error CS0453: The type `T' must be a non-nullable value type in order
>   to use it as type parameter `T' in the generic type or method
>   `System.Nullable'

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to add a generic type constraint to your class declaration.

Comment: Thanks, I got it: `class MyClass<T> where T : struct`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only `struct`s can be `Nullable<T>` so add a constraint.

```
class MyClass<T> where T : struct
```